# Azure event hub processor doesn't work with enterprise proxy

Tags: azure-eventhub

I am working with Azure event hub sender and processor tutorial and I'am sitting behind a enterprise proxy.

Sending events to the event hub works really fine, but i have problems to let get eventHubProcessor access to the Azur event hub. It seems to me that I have some proxy problems.

I use

- DefaultEndpointProtocol=https

as storage connection string and I set

- ServiceBusEnvironment.SystemConnectivity.Mode =
  ConnectivityMode.Https;

I also tryed many different variations to set the proxy in App.config file. E.g.

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="proxyGroup">
      <section name="basicProxy" type="Proxy.Configuration.CustomProxySection, Proxy" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

 <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true" >
      <proxy usesystemdefault="true"/>
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

Witout any success :(

At "eventProcessorHost.RegisterEventProcessorAsync(options).Wait();" I get the exception

```
  InnerException: 
   HResult=-2146233087
   Message=Der angeforderte Name ist gültig, es wurden jedoch keine Daten des angeforderten Typs gefunden
   Source=Microsoft.ServiceBus
   StackTrace:
     Server stack trace: 
     Exception rethrown at [0]: 
        bei Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
        bei Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Amqp.Transport.WebSocketTransportInitiator.Complete(IAsyncResult connectAsyncResult, Boolean completeSynchronously)
     Exception rethrown at [1]: 
        bei Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
        bei Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Amqp.AmqpMessagingFactory.ConnectAsyncResult.<GetAsyncSteps>b__9d(ConnectAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
        bei Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
     Exception rethrown at [2]: 
        bei Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
        bei Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Amqp.AmqpMessagingFactory.EndCreateConnection(IAsyncResult result)
        bei Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Amqp.FaultTolerantObject`1.CreateAsyncResult.<GetAsyncSteps>b__1(CreateAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
        bei Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
     Exception rethrown at [3]: 
        bei Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
        bei Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult`1.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

Does anyone has an idea??
Many many thanks for your time.

Regards, Roland

Answer (score 0):

Reason for the problem is that ServicePointManager does not support proxys in case of HTTPS.

To solve the problem change everything to HTTP

In your main program:

```
string storageConnectString=string.Format("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;....");
ServiceBusEnvironment.SystemConnectivity.Mode = ConnectivityMode.Http;
```

In your App.config

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true" >
    <proxy
      autoDetect="false"
      bypassonlocal="true"
      proxyaddress="http://##.###.###.###:8080"
      usesystemdefault="false"/>
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```